# AC voltage and frequency as complex number?

Tags: voltage, ac, theory, frequency-response

For some software I am writing, I coded classes of electrical systems that receive a voltage and return the current response.

For the DC case that's easy: I pass a real number as argument, the voltage, and return another real number, the current.

Now I need to extend this to the AC case and I need to pass the AC voltage and frequency and return the current and phase.

I was thinking of using complex numbers for this.

Is there any common representation of voltage and frequency as a complex number?

I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Voltage and phase are commonly represented as phasors, basically a complex number representation: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phasors.html

Comment: You should probably use a search engine to look up "phasor" and also "AC analysis". The phasor is a way to use a complex number to represent an AC voltage or current. The phasor representation does not capture frequency, however. In the systems you are considering, is there only ever a single AC frequency? The situation is more difficult if there is more than one frequency.

Comment: flxh, *The Art of Electronics*, 2nd and 3rd editions at least (can't speak to the 1st edition that I never bought), go into it in detail in the first chapter, or so.

Comment: I am familiar with the current/voltage + phase representation as a complex number. However the current and phase response are dependent on the voltage AND frequency which I want to represent as a complex number. Basically a function that maps Voltage + Frequency -> Current + Phase

Comment: @flxh I don't understand. If you *are* familiar with [representing voltage and current as complex numbers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/272823/38098), then what's the question again? Can you illustrate -- provide a specific, concrete case to make your point -- what you are wanting to achieve? I'm feeling confused.

Comment: So usually current and phase are encoded as complex number, right? The information of the frequency of the sinusoidal is missing. Is there a representation of amplitude and frequency as complex number? For example I want to simulate a photovoltaic inverter. Its modelled efficiency  depends on the AC bus frequency and voltage. So I wanted to encode the information of ac voltage and frequency as a complex number as input for the response function. The function returns the current and phase relative to the voltage phase.

Comment: @flxh *"Is there a representation of amplitude and frequency as complex number?"* -- Not readily imaginable to me, though that doesn't mean some bright person couldn't come up with one. I think amplitude is time-domain. Is that how you mean it? Frequency is... well... frequency-domain to me. If so, I haven't seen someone use that pairing as a complex number before. Also, are you discussing an output in current and an input in voltage? So transconductance? Perhaps you could write a little more in your question?

Comment: @flxh This isn't quite an answer to the question you actually asked, but it sounds like you may want to look into the Laplace-domain representation of your circuit?

Comment: This may be of some interest (it is about using Euler's formula to represent a complex valued function): https://www.cs.ccu.edu.tw/~wtchu/courses/2012s_DSP/Lectures/Lecture%203%20Complex%20Exponential%20Signals.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any common representation of voltage and frequency as a complex number?

You shouldn't do this.

First, as others have pointed out, complex numbers are often used to represent the magnitude and **phase** of AC voltage and current signals, so using a complex number to represent magnitude and frequency would be confusing.

Second, you may find you want to find your circuit's response to voltage inputs with different phases (for example, if the input to this circuit is the output of another circuit), and then you will want to use a complex value (representing voltage and phase) for the input of your circuit.

Third, if your circuit is linear (and if it isn't, you will have other problems with your approach), then the frequency of every voltage and current signal in the circuit is the same. So there's no point storing the frequency value over and over again for each variable in the circuit. Keep it in one variable that applies to the whole circuit. (Very likely you'll soon want to sweep this variable and get a different solution for a range of frequencies the circuit might be operated at).

Fourth, there's no value in it. When we use complex numbers to represent magnitude and phase of signals, we can also use the rules of complex math (for example, when two complex numbers are multiplied, the phase of the result is equal to the sum of the phases of the operands). This allows us to extend the concept of resistance into the complex domain as *impedance* and treat inductors and capacitors very simply when analyzing linear AC circuits. There's no such benefit if we use a complex number to represent magnitude and frequency (indeed, we are left with the problem of how to represent the phase of our signal).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To go a bit more into detail: I want to simulate the response of multiple elements connected to an AC Bus. Then I search for the voltage where the sum of currents is 0. This works very well for the DC case. But for the AC case I need to search across voltage and frequency to find the root, where active power and reactive power of all elements sum up to 0. So in that sense representing it by a complex number would an advantage since there are many root finding methods working for complex numbers.

Comment: @flxh, they only work if your system uses the ordinary rules for complex math. You'll have to show that the equations you want to use will be simplified by using these rules if you want to convince me of your idea.

Comment: Algorithm I wrote for finding the root in the DC case would work with with complex numbers too. It is a variant of the secant method, basically. Then it would be a true generalization because the DC case would be the same with both imaginary parts 0 (frequency for the Voltage and phasor for the current response).

Comment: Share the equations if you can.

Comment: https://www.frassek.org/numerik/nullstellen-komplexer-funktionen/ein-schritt-verfahren-komplex/#Sekanten In the DC case I simulate the current of each element for a given bus voltage. The I use the secant method to find the voltage where the sum of currents is 0. This is the converged state of all elements connected to the same bus.

Comment: @flxh, when you do the division \$\frac{z_i-z_{i-1}}{f(z_i)-f(z_{i-1})}\$ I don't think you're going to get a sensible result with your method because you'll mix up the frequency and response components. More likely you should be looking for a voltage that produces the desired output current for each frequency, or you should be searching for a frequency that produces the desired output current for a given voltage...not trying to optimize both frequency and input voltage at the same time.

Comment: If you really want to do what you said, you might look at [Broyden's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method), which generalizes the secant method to multi-dimensional problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with a voltage or current, a phase shift and a frequency. So you need three numbers, not only two when using complex numbers with the real and imaginary part.

So I would try to make a user defined type, either of three real numbers or a complex number and a real number.

Comment: So actually I only need two values for the argument and return value. Voltage and Frequency for argument and current + relative phase for the response.

Comment: But maybe I need to do some simplifications