# What is the imaginary part of a phasor expressing?

Tags: phasor

Lets say we have a sinusoidal signal in the form

\$V = A e^{j\omega t}\$

We can also write this as

\$V = A(\cos(\omega t) + i\sin(\omega t))\$

If we plot this signal, we see the real part of above equation, so a cosine function. See this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Unfasor.gif) for example. As far as I understand the signal *itself* is the cosine function.

What kind of information do we get out of the imaginary part, so the sine function? I can only imagine the phase of the signal, right?

Comment: The voltage is taken as the real part (which is why cos is chosen over sin.) The use of Euler's and complex numbers is that multiplication of two complex numbers involves both scaling and rotation. By keeping the scaling part equal to 1, it reduces to rotation alone. (The voltage vector and current vector magnitudes stay fixed while they rotate around in a circle at the same rate, but not necessarily from the same starting position.) You need the imaginary part to make that happen correctly. There are other ways. But they are way, way harder to keep track of. This makes it all easy algebra.

Comment: Consider a complex number of the form a+jb. We can combine the real and imaginary parts of this complex number to obtain the phase but also we can combine the real and imaginary parts of this complex number to obtain the magnitude.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write a nice walk-through. The YouTube author, 3blue1brown, has some really good videos on a closely related topic. (Not electronics, but the geometries of complex number operations... including 3D operations with quaternions.) Meantime, I have something that may help a tiny bit [written here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/272823/38098). The usual answers will be about 'phase'. And that's true enough. But it is a static (snapshot) view. You need to also see this as a dynamic process where multiplication means rotation and where time can be introduced.

Comment: "*If we plot this signal, we see the real part of above equation, so a cosine function*" -- no, you see the *magnitude*, which is \$A\$ (or \$\sqrt{\Re^2+\Im^2}\$), with a phase given by \$\arctan(\Im/\Re)\$. The important bit is that **both** parts are needed. What you're referring to, about the real part, is true for active power, for example.

Comment: it is basically phase. Every time you multiply 1 by i, you rotate by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

In your question, as stated, none.  There is useful information embedded in \$A\$: by convention it's a complex number with some gain and phase.  But strictly speaking there's no *useful* information in your \$A\$, because it's just the driving voltage -- where useful information is to be had it's when you compare the system *output* with the system *input*.

**Long and winding answer**:

This is confusing because it involves a shortcut that's rarely emphasized.

Start with the hard way:  If you want to see what happens when you excite a circuit by a sine wave at one frequency, you can let the input voltage be \$V = A \cos \omega t\$.  Then you can observe that the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table) of that is \$\mathcal L \left \lbrace A \cos \omega t \right \rbrace = \frac{A s}{s^2 + \omega^2} = \frac{A}{2} \left (\frac{1}{s + j\omega} + \frac{1}{s - j\omega} \right ) \$.

If you wanted to do a Laplace-domain analysis of a circuit's response to \$ A\cos \omega t\$, you could first derive its transfer function, then find it's response to \$\frac{A}{2} \left (\frac{1}{s + j\omega} + \frac{1}{s - j\omega} \right )\$, then work out that the result is some linear combination of \$ \cos \omega t\$ and \$\sin \omega t\$.  This involves finding the response to \$\frac{A}{2} \frac{1}{s + j\omega}\$ and the response to \$\frac{A}{2} \frac{1}{s - j\omega}\$ (note the change in the sign of the \$j \omega\$ term), adding them together, doing partial fraction expansion, etc., and getting an answer.

**BUT**: it turns out (and when you get further in your studies you can prove this to yourself) that *arithmetically*, all you need to do is find the response to \$\frac{A}{2} \frac{1}{s + j\omega}\$, i.e. \$V_{out^+} = \frac{A}{2} k_+ \frac{1}{s + j\omega}\$, where \$k_+\$ is some complex number.

You can do this, because if all of the component values (capacitances, inductances, resistances) are real numbered, then the response to the negative frequency part, \$\frac{A}{2} \frac{1}{s - j\omega}\$ is just \$V_{out^-} = \frac{A}{2} k_- \frac{1}{s - j\omega}\$, where \$k_- = k_+^*\$, i.e. \$k_-\$ is just the complex conjugate of \$k_+\$.

This leads to all sorts of arithmetic simplifications in doing your circuit analysis -- but at the cost (until you do the above proof that I suggest) of having to just follow directions, and assuring yourself intuitively that they're correct.  Basically, you do your analysis as if \$V\$ really is complex, then you get your answer -- and the complex gain (that \$k_+\$ that I mention) tells you the gain *and the phase shift* of the circuit at that frequency.

For most practical circuit analysis problems, this is enough, and if you're neither curious nor driven to understanding the underlying math, you can just get by on that.  I got by *just fine* on this, in fact, until I found myself wanting to give some students a theoretical justification for it -- and that happened after decades of doing just fine designing circuits and control loops using the shortcut without worrying about it.

Answer (score 2):

The imaginary part gives us the phase at any point in time.  This is the analytical form.

Real signals can't be imaginary, of course, and we need two signals to represent a phase relationship in practice.

Comment: The imaginary part is not the phase. The phase can be calculated from both the real and imaginary parts together; so can the amplitude.

Comment: I disagree with you Tim. The phasor itself is the compaction of the amplitude and phase of the real signal. A complex number can be thought of as a vector, that vector has a magnitude and angle. The magnitude is the amplitude of the real signal and the angle is the phase of the real signal. The angle of the complex number offset from the real number line is the phase. It could be lagging (negative, or below the real axis) or leading (positive, ahead above the real axis).

Comment: I'll correct myself since you said instantaneous, which I missed. The imaginary part contributes to be other the instantaneous amplitude and phase however.

Comment: @Melendowski Yeah, the question is something of a corruption of the term, as a phasor is traditionally an AC steady-state thing, not a time-variant thing. For taking the value at a point in time, you get a complex number, the argument of which tells phase at that point, so this seems a reasonable explanation of the equation as applied to signals.  The real question though is why this has been called a phasor.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginary part of a phasor expresses reactive values which come from reactive components expressed in electrical models by L or C which affects the polarity of "i".  It's a play on words, because the parts are not imaginary but and they can stored energy then release it then an alternating cycle of current passes thru them the net power is zero. So it is not counted as "real". Hence the term "imaginary" or also known as reactive for temporary storage.

The real part comes only from resistance R.

Since reactive components may store either voltage (C) or current (L) when excited with alternating voltage the current will push and pull like a spring , so does not consume real power over one or many cycles. Like a spring mass, it may exert a force (current) in either polarity thus the net average current or power is considered "imaginary" .

Where as real power times time converts energy ino heat or mechanical power.

### Other info

Inductors all have some resistance and thus some real power is used and shown on right +X horizontal axis.  Negative real current comes from power sources.

Positive imaginary current (+ve "i or j") comes from Inductance while -ve "i" currents come from  Capacitance and are plotted on the -Y vertical axis.

Conductors have "real" resistance, R and some inductance depending how they are made sometimes overlooked. Ideal inductors do not exist so there is always some resistance, then the ratios become interesting.

All Insulators are mainly capacitive with some cosine voltage due to electrode series resistance and/or leakage parallel resistance. But ideal C models have no resistance.

Comment: The word "imaginary" supposedly comes from the mathematicians who discovered them being convinced that such a thing could not actually exist.

Comment: ok "the square of a number that is not only odd but negative" hard to imagine at first -1. I must read the book on this.

Comment: Wikipedia claims it was René Descartes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number

Answer (score 1):

A·e<sup>(jωt)</sup> isn't a real wave; it's a complex voltage source used to understand the frequency response of a system.

Once you know response of system for this wave, you can use linearity and get response for a cosine wave cos(jωt) = A·e<sup>jωt</sup> + A·e<sup>(-jωt)</sup> or any other phased cosine wave, since phase is just multiplying the respons with A·e<sup>jφ</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

You said that let's assume we have the next signal \$V = A e^{j\omega t}\$

I have kept in my hands radar and radio parts where that assumption was true when those parts were in their normal places and in use.

Virtually everyone has today on DSP based devices where this also is true as digitized signals.

There are available some linear ICs where this is also true. They are phase locked loops and advanced modulators, detectors or mixers. I guess you also have spotted or will spot text I-channel and Q-channel in the functional diagrams of such ICs.

In analog circuits mentioned above the complex valued signal exists  as 2 separate voltages (against GND) in 2 wires - one wire for the real part and one wire for the imaginary part. The mentioned I-channel has the real part and the Q-channel has the imaginary part.

In DSP one digital sample of a complex signal needs two memory words. One word is for the real part and the other is for the imaginary part.

Not asked: Some confusion may be caused by the fact that also pure real valued signals (=single voltage) are often presented as their integral transforms which are complex valued and offer many benefits by streamlining common important calculations. The most common such thing is the phasor calculus of AC circuits.